# Is it safe to call dict.__init__ on already populated dictionary?

Tags: python

I have a class that inherits from the built in `dict` class. It used to look a bit like:

```
class AwesomeDictionary(dict):
    def __init__(self, *args, **args):
        self['hello'] = 'world'
        i = {}
        dict.__init__(i, *args, **kargs)
        self.update(i)
```

I implemented it like that with a temporary dictionary because I thought `__init__` would create a brand new dictionary or at least clear it.

I only recently realized that you can do something like this in the Python interpreter with no problems:

```
f = {'hi':56, '67':89}
dict.__init__(f, **{'h':67})
print f
#You get:  {'67': 89, 'h': 67, 'hi': 56}
```

and if you specify the same field:

```
f = {'hi':56, '67':89}
dict.__init__(f, **{'hi':34})
print f
#You get:  {'67': 89, 'hi': 34}
```

So, in that case, it would appear that `__init__` is acting the same as `.update`.

Is there a particular reason why this is the case and can I expect this to be consistent across implementations and versions?

On a similar note, is there any purpose for calling `.update` on a regular dictionary other than perhaps code cleainliness and readability (which is a perfectly fine reason mind you, I was just wondering if that is the only reason)?

Oh and I know I could just leave it as is and do an update for peace of mind, but it feels quite inefficient if you are doing the same thing twice.

I apologize if this is a silly question.

Thanks for your time.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can also call `f.__init__(hi=34)`.

The `__init__` method on objects is the *initializer*. It is called to initialize a newly created object, and usually the method assumes that the object is still fresh and empty when `__init__` is executed.

If you call it again at a later time, if it'll work depends on the class. For `dict` it apparently works. I would not count on this working across versions, the behaviour of the `dict.__init__` method you observed is not specified in the documentation. It just so happens that in CPython, `__init__` is implemented as a `self.update()` (albeit in C).

The biggest drawback is that it will confuse anyone trying to understand your code. Why call `__init__` when `.update()` is so much clearer?

Comment: I don't think that you can expect `dict.__init__` to behave like `dict.update` across different python implementations because there is nothing that says it *must* behave that way (although I don't see *why* it would have any reason to behave differently).  In any event, +1 for "why call `__init__` when `update` is so much cleaner"

Comment: Ah, excellent. I figured as much. Thanks mate.

Oh and I would never call `__init__` on a regular shmoe dictionary. If it was standardized, I'd only call it if I was inheriting from `dict` or something. :)